# Reshape numpy (n,) vector to (n,1) vector

Tags: python, numpy

So it is easier for me to think about vectors as column vectors when I need to do some linear algebra. Thus I prefer shapes like (n,1).

Is there significant memory usage difference between shapes (n,) and (n,1)?

What is preferred way?

And how to reshape (n,) vector into (n,1) vector. Somehow b.reshape((n,1)) doesn't do the trick.

```
a = np.random.random((10,1))
b = np.ones((10,))
b.reshape((10,1))
print(a)
print(b)

[[ 0.76336295]
 [ 0.71643237]
 [ 0.37312894]
 [ 0.33668241]
 [ 0.55551975]
 [ 0.20055153]
 [ 0.01636735]
 [ 0.5724694 ]
 [ 0.96887004]
 [ 0.58609882]]
[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
```

Comment: oh okey. Somehow I thougt that  np.reshape and other np.methods don't modify in place but obj.reshape or obj.method do modify. Ok thanks

Comment: `b.shape=(10,1)` is the syntax for an in-place reshape.

Answer (score 21):

More simpler way with python syntax sugar is to use

```
b.reshape(-1,1)
```

where the system will automatically compute the correct shape instead "-1"

Comment: This works, but you will still have to do `b_new = b.reshape(-1, 1)` to assign the reshaped copy to a variable as Ilja Everilä pointed out.

Answer (score 16):

[`ndarray.reshape()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape) returns a new view, or a copy (depends on the new shape). It does not modify the array in place.

```
b.reshape((10, 1))
```

as such is effectively no-operation, since the created view/copy is not assigned to anything. The "fix" is simple:

```
b_new = b.reshape((10, 1))
```

The amount of memory used should not differ at all between the 2 shapes. Numpy arrays use the concept of [strides](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/advanced/advanced_numpy/#indexing-scheme-strides) and so the dimensions `(10,)` and `(10, 1)` can both use the same buffer; the amounts to jump to next row and column just change.

Comment: Can you kindly elaborate more on the difference between (10,) and (10,1)? Namely,  (10,) has no definition for the second size? when will it be defined if ever? upon assigning a value? (I am new to python moving from matlab)

Comment: An array of shape `(10,)` is a 1-dimensional "row" vector, as can be seen in the question's printout. Shape `(10, 1)` produces a column vector, or a matrix of 10 rows, 1 column.