# Matplotlib: Gaussian contour plot from two arrays

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two numpy arrays, one of shape (239,2) containing my data points and one of shape (239,) containing the values of a bivariate gaussian density for these data points.

How can I create a contour plot with Matplotlib for my density function on top of a scatter plot of the data points?

Currently I get a `TypeError: Input z must be a 2D array`, when trying to use the `contour` function in matplotlib. Why does z have to be 2D if I have a value for  the X-axis, Y-axis and probability density for every data point? Do I need to interpolate in some way?

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c='green')
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c='orange')
ax.contour(z, X[:,0], X[:,1])           <-- TypeError happens here
plt.show()
```

X is of shape (239, 2), z is of shape (239,)

Comment: You should look at the documentation. It highlights the specific requirements for the data shape: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contour.html

Comment: It mentions that `z` needs to be of the same shape as `x` and `y` so you could try reshaping `z` to be of shape `(239,1)` as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549331/reshape-numpy-n-vector-to-n-1-vector?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

`contour` needs z values on a regular 2D grid, perhaps your data is better suitable for the [`tricontour`](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/tricontour_smooth_delaunay.html#sphx-glr-gallery-images-contours-and-fields-tricontour-smooth-delaunay-py) method:

```
from matplotlib.tri import Triangulation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.random.random((100))
y = np.random.random((100))
z = x * y

tri = Triangulation(x,y)

plt.tricontour(tri, z, )
plt.scatter(x,y, c=z)
plt.show()
```